# logcat -f /sdcard/log.log -r 1024 -n 30 -v time & produces only 4 logs instead of 30

Tags: android, logcat, android-4.4-kitkat

Performing Stability Testing on a rooted device running kitkat.
I executed the follow command in the shell:

```
logcat -f /sdcard/log.log -r 1024 -n 30 -v time &
```

This command **should** produce 30 logs with a size of about a 1MB, however in Kitkat only 4 logs are created with each log size is around 17KB.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Defaults are 16K and 4, so it looks like your numeric options are being ignored.  Anything odd about how you are launching this?  You might want to check the source code and see if there have been any changes.

Comment: In regards to anything odd about launching? No, just bringing up a cmd  prompt where the adb is located and then cd into shell and running the  above command.